# Text inside minipage doesn't touch the border of the page

Tags: minipage, border

I have a heading that is made out of two minipages, one with a logo on the left and one with some text to the right. Neither of them touch the borders of the page as does the rest of the text (when using `showframe` package, there's a little gap between the border and whatever's in the minipage.

This is what I have:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\noindent{
\begin{minipage}{0.20\textwidth}
    \vspace{-2.5pt}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{IMAGE}
\end{minipage}
}
\hfill
\noindent{
\begin{minipage}{0.70\textwidth}    
    \noindent{Class code and name \hfill Professor name, semester}
    
    \noindent{My name and student id number \hfill date}
\end{minipage}
}
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

There's a little gap that I'd like to get rid of. None of the other parts of the document exhibit this gap. All text touches both sides of the border.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! `\noindent` doesn't use an argument, so remove the braces. Also the second noindent is useless, since you don't start a new paragraph.

Comment: @WilliamA.Noble did the answer meet your requirements - do let us know

Comment: The braces were it. They were adding some padding around the text and image. @Bernard Could you add your suggestion as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Look at your second minipage:

```
\noindent{
\begin{minipage}{0.70\textwidth}    
    \noindent{Class code and name \hfill Professor name, semester}
    
    \noindent{My name and student id number \hfill date}
\end{minipage}
}
```

You have the space after `\end{minipage}` before the final `}` after which you have second space. Following `\par` removes only single space by build-in TeX paragraph algorithm. So you can do:

```
\noindent{
\begin{minipage}{0.70\textwidth}    
    \noindent{Class code and name \hfill Professor name, semester}
    
    \noindent{My name and student id number \hfill date}
\end{minipage}% <- a space was here
}
```

Now, you have only single space after final `}` and it is removed by `\par`. But much better is do not use irrelevant `{...}` prefixed by `\noindent`:

```
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.20\textwidth}
    \vspace{-2.5pt}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.70\textwidth}
    \noindent Class code and name\hfill Professor name, semester

    \noindent My name and student id number \hfill date
\end{minipage}
```

Note that there was a space after first `\noindent{` so your image was shifted by one space right too. Now, there is no space because the end of line is at the end of control sequence. The second `\noindent` was irrelevant (in horizontal mode) and `\noindent`s inside the minipage are used without irrelevant `{...}`. Now, the space after `\end{minipage}` is only single space and it is removed by following `\par` (empty line generates `\par` and it starts paragraph building algorithm if TeX is in horizontal mode).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0.1cm]{article}


\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \vspace{-2.5pt}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{IMAGE}
    \end{minipage}%
\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}    
        \noindent{Class code and name \hfill Professor name, semester}
        \noindent{My name and student id number \hfill date}
    \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

**OR**

```
\documentclass[border=0.1cm]{article}


\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        \vspace{-2.5pt}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{IMAGE}
    \end{minipage}%
\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}    
        Class code and name \hfill Professor name, semester\\       
        My name and student id number \hfill date
    \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Top alignment**

```
\documentclass[border=0.1cm]{article}


\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        \vspace{-2.5pt}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{IMAGE}
    \end{minipage}}%
\hfill%
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}    
        Class code and name \hfill Professor name, semester\\       
        My name and student id number \hfill date
    \end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. May I ask, what is the `border=0.1cm` for?

Comment: a carry over from copy and paste -- please ignore it -- not related to your solution